# JSON.parse not able to parse valid JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

JSON.parse throws error when I try to parse a valid JSON object. My issue is i'm receiving data from webservice and sometimes it works with parse and sometimes it doesn't not sure what is the reason why. I would expect JSON.parse to return same object if its a valid JSON object? or parse it if its a string.

```
 var obj1= { Result: Inprogress };
 var json = JSON.parse(obj1);
```

please help me with this understanding

Comment: There is no such thing as a "JSON object". JSON is a string.

Comment: @Stumblor yes, Tomalak is correct. JSON is a serialization scheme. The OP here is talking about a **JavaScript** object, not a JSON object.

Comment: @Stumblor Point #1: Don't link to w3schools as a reference source. They are not credible and should not be used. The JSON reference source is http://json.org/. Point #2: JSON always is a string. If you think differently, you are making the same mistake as the OP.

Comment: @Tomalak perhaps you could provide an alternative reference then, so that we don't continue making the mistake?

Comment: @Stumblor Perhaps you read my comment again. ;-) No need to become all defensive. You were wrong, that's all. But it's a very common mistake to make, and we are here to learn, right?

Comment: Your code should look like to be ok:
    var obj1 = '{ "Result": "Inprogress" }';
    var json = JSON.parse(obj1);

Comment: But ofcourse JSON object exists, that having methods `parse` and `stringify` ... Btw. @Stumblor Even in the w3schools article you've linked they say : "... but the JSON format is text only ..."

Comment: why do I get downvote :(

Comment: still I didn't get proper answer why do the JSON.parse method fails if its valid object !!

Comment: @DanFisher Please re-read Pointy's answer carefully, it says "The `JSON.parse()` method takes a __string__ argument ...", you're passing an object. Also reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) might help you to understand this better.

Comment: @Teemu Yep - next time I'll read all the way till the end! Consider myself heartily corrected.

Comment: @teemu is it not javascript is suppose to be free from dataypes?

Comment: [Not quite](https://es5.github.io/#x8). Are you still wrestling with this?

Answer (score 2):

What you have there is a JavaScript object. It doesn't need to be parsed because it's plain JavaScript syntax and JavaScript itself parses it. JSON is a serialization format.

The `JSON.parse()` method takes a **string** argument, like one retrieved from an ajax call or from local storage or some other source of data that only deals in string values.

Comment: but why JSON.parse throws error...? we can't parse javascript object to JSON?

Comment: @DanFisher If you want to convert a JavaScript object to a JSON string, use `JSON.stringify()`. The verb "to parse" describes the process of interpreting text (contents of a string), so "parse to JSON" is backwards and doesn't make sense.

Comment: I understand that my question is i'm receiving the object/string from someone else and i'm not sure about which one it is. I get error sometimes and I don't get error sometimes. I want to know why JSON.parse gives error when its a valid object!!!

Comment: @DanFisher well, if it *really* is a valid blob of JSON syntax, then you won't get an error. The JSON parser is pretty strict.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is malformed. A right JSON is

```
{ "Result": "Inprogress" }
```

You have forgotten the `""` character in beginning and in end of each part of your JSON.