# Unable to parse valid JSON from textarea element with JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json, forms, parsing, textarea

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51305901/parsing-json-data-from-textarea-with-javascript/51306060), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699781/json-parse-not-able-to-parse-valid-json-object), and similar ones did not help.

The JSON below is valid.

However, invoking `JSON.parse` throws an error.

How can you parse valid JSON from a textarea element?

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6gpdL81e/

```js
let text = document.getElementById("testBox").value;
let jsonObject = JSON.parse(text);
```

```html
<textarea id="testBox">
    
      {
      "name": "Foobar",
      "favorite_pets": ["capybara", "lizard"],
      "favorite_fruits": ["avocado"],
      "address": {
       "city": "FairyVille",
       "street": "42 Main St."
      }
    }
    
    </textarea>
```

Comment: It's having an issue with some of your whitespace characters.

Comment: What do you recommend as a solution? Users upload text like this, so we need some automated mechanism to scrub the text. Just remove all leading/trailing whitespace?

Comment: You could `$('#testBox').val().replace(/[^!-~]/g, '');` to effectively remove all characters that fall outside of the char range 33-126, but really I wouldn't clean it and would just return an error to the user if the parse fails.  Because there could legitimately be a valid parse error that you are going to have to handle.

Answer (score 1):

It because jQuery using non-breaking space `nbsp` or charcode `\xA0` not normal space. you need to replace it.

```js
let text = $('#testBox').val();
let jsonObject;
try {
  jsonObject = JSON.parse(text);
} catch (ex) {
  console.log("error: ", ex.message)
}
text = text.replace(/\xA0/g, " "); // or \s but will also replace newline
jsonObject = JSON.parse(text);
console.log("what the name: ", jsonObject.name)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="testBox">
  {
  "name": "Foobar",
  "favorite_pets": ["capybara", "lizard"],
  "favorite_fruits": ["avocado"],
  "address": {
   "city": "FairyVille",
   "street": "42 Main St."
  }
}

</textarea>
```